# Is it possible to do a two-stage load in a single Azure Data Factory Data Flow?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pair of target tables which have a foreign key realtionship. The primary key of the parent table is generated by a database sequence on insert so the insert into the child table has to be performed after the parent's primary key has been generated.

I want to insert a pair of records into the tables as a single transaction in Azure Data Factory.

Is it possible, in a single DataFlow, to insert into the parent table, and then insert into the child using a value from the newly inserted record? I have a legacy key value in the parent that I can use to identify the newly generated primary key.

In SQL terms, the insert into the child would look like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO child_table
( foreign_key
, some_data_value
)
SELECT
  parent_table.primary_key
, staging_table.some_data_value
FROM staging_table
JOIN parent_table
  ON parent_table.legacy_value = staging_table.legacy_value
```

DataFlows can have Custom Sink Ordering, in which the order of table inserts can be set, but in this case I need the Source step that retrieves the value to execute after the Sink step that loads the parent.

Separating it out into two DataFlows has two drawbacks, in that the two inserts are not encapsulated in a single transaction, and the cluster start up overhead time happens twice.

Comment: What's the database platform?

Comment: @wBob Azure SQL, we are exploring the possibility of either inserting via a view with an on-insert trigger to pick up the foreign key, or writing a stored procedure to do the inserts. But actually the DB platform is not finally decided yet, it might end up being MS Dataverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is "No you can't, not just with ADF anyway".

What we would need to do to work around this is to build something in the database, such as a view with an on-insert trigger that looks up the foreign key and substitutes the value.